# Statically linking dependencies using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, static, vst

I have a VST plug-in which I have built on Windows using Visual Studio. It depends on two libraries (FFTW and Speex). I am able to link these to the project and it compiles - so far so good.

However, the problem is that I cannot get the plug-in to compile without requiring the .dll files at runtime - I have looked elsewhere on this site, found suggestions, and tried the following in Visual Studio:

- Ensuring Configuration->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies contain the .lib files I am looking to link
- Ensuring Configuration->Linker->Additional Library Directories contain the directories of my .lib files
- Making sure Configuration->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library is set to MultiThreaded /MT

Yet, when I check using Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/), my plug-in still requires the .dll files.

The host with which I am looking to use the plug-in cannot load the VST if it has .dll dependencies (I have tried another host and it works fine, as long as the .dll files are in the same directory as the plug-in .dll file).

I would really like this plug-in to link statically to these libraries, can anyone help?

Thanks!

Adam

p.s. - as a check, I made a simple plug-in with no dependencies and compiled it and this loads in the host no problem

Comment: Clearly you are linking wrong .lib files.  The import library of a DLL also has the .lib filename extension.  You'll need to obtain the static library build for these components.  Not always available, they are very dependent on the specific compiler and CRT versions.  A DLL can be much less troublesome that way.  Always build from source to avoid misery.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I created the .lib files from .def files according to this page: http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html - is there some command to force them to be static builds?

Comment: That always creates an import library.  No, of course not.